# Android. В чём разница между методами getChildAt() и getVirtualChildAt() у TableRow?

Tags: android, android-view

Они оба ведь возвращают дочерний элемент по индексу...

Answer (score 0):

Разница будет когда в дочерних элементах будет использован `android:layout_span` больше единицы.

Иначе говоря этот метод возвращает "ребенка" не по  порядковому номеру как `getChildAt()`, а возвращает `View` находящееся в данной колонке.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `getChildAt` определён в родительском классе `ViewGroup`, [пример реализации](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#6907):

```java
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= mChildrenCount) {
        return null;
    }
    return mChildren[index];
}
```

Доступ в [`TableRow::getVirtualChildAt`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TableRow.java#130) строится через промежуточный массив индексов `mColumnToChildIndex`, в котором колонки отображаются на дочерние элементы, то есть, сначала лениво вычисляется индекс, а затем вызывается родительский метод `getChildAt`:

```java
public View getVirtualChildAt(int i) {
    if (mColumnToChildIndex == null) {
       mapIndexAndColumns();
    }
    final int deflectedIndex = mColumnToChildIndex.get(i, -1);
    if (deflectedIndex != -1) {
        return getChildAt(deflectedIndex);
    }
    return null;
}
```